# InstallShield - Get version of a file

Tags: installation, installshield

I am using InstallShield 2010 and was wondering if anyone knows how to do the following:

I want to get the version of my main exe within my installer and make it the name of my setup.exe InstallShield is generating. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to use the Automation services to accomplish this, which is the programming interface for InstallShield. Whenever I build my project in Visual Studio for my exe I run an exe in the Post-build that sets the InstallSheild project to be the same version.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you could do this....depending on your IS project type (MSI, installscript, etc.)

1) create a variable such as Product_Name in the Property Manager, set it in your installscript and retrieve it to modify your *.exe name

2) Using SQL, you can programatically get the product_name and set the *.exe name. Search the Direct Editor (Installation Designer -> Additional Tools -> Direct Editor) for the exact location of the table/value you need. For example (below), using VBScript, I modify the path to the installation root of the files I pull into the IS project. Similarly this can be done for any table in the IS Direct Editor. Using a tool such as Visual build Pro I believe would help you out as well. It's well worth the ~$100!

```
    Set oMSI = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
    On Error Resume Next

    ' open ISM file in transacted mode
    Set oDB = oMSI.OpenDatabase("C:\Path\to\myProject.ism", 1)

    strQuery = "Select * FROM `ISPathVariable` WHERE `ISPathVariable`.`ISPathVariable` = 'InstallTreeFolder'"

'////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
'// Update Path Variable

' fetch the one and only samplesource record
Set oView = oDB.OpenView(strQuery)
oView.Execute
Set oRec = oView.Fetch

' change field 2, the Value field
oRec.StringData(2) = "%INSTALL_TREE_ROOT%"

' update the changed record
oView.Modify 2, oRec

' close the view, commit changes, clean up
oView.Close: oDB.Commit: Set oMSI = Nothing
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion (#1), but InstallShield does not let you use variables in the Setup File Name.